# How long does an added index take to take effect?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Possibly a silly question, but like the title states, how long does it take for an index to take effect after it has been added to the table? I have a table with about a million rows.

Comment: it depends on your computer

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  (There was a significant change starting in 5.6.)